# How to Get Eclipse to Recognize a Git Worktree?

Tags: git, eclipse, git-worktree

I have a git repository from which I created several worktrees. Eclipse only recognizes the git repository if I import a project from the main worktree. However, when I import projects from the additional worktrees I created, Eclipse doesn't recognize these as git repositories and doesn't show any history.

The worktrees are created in different directories from the main worktrees and Eclipse is started in a different workspace for them.

I intend to use those worktrees for code reviews without affecting the master branch or any development branch I'm working on.

Visual Studio Code seems to have no problem with the additional worktrees. When opening a project in the additional worktree, I can see the history of the different files in **timeline** tab.

Comment: VS Code just delegates to the command line Git (git-core). In contrast, Eclipse does not use or require git-core, but is based on JGit, a Git implementation in Java, that does not support Git worktree yet (there is a contribution that have not yet approved): https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477475

Comment: @howlger Thank you for your comment. Any idea when this change would be approved?

Comment: I have no idea. You might vote for or comment on the bug and/or help to [improve the contribution according to the given review comments](https://git.eclipse.org/r/c/jgit/jgit/+/171267/4#message-689e82cc0d6f72a4709be4e7503e4cb505f22ac7).